# Value of type '[Businessdata]' has no member 'objectAtIndex'

Tags: ios, swift, search, uisearchbar

I am try to implement search bar to my table view. But I am getting this error in one function. Don't know how to solve??

```
Value of type '[Businessdata]' has no member 'objectAtIndex'
```

**My code**

```
 var arrDict = [Businessdata]()

    func searchMethod(notification:NSNotification)
    {

        isSearching = true;

        let text:String = notification.userInfo!["text"] as! String;

        arrSearch = [];

        for(var i=0;i<arrDict.count;i++)
        {
            if((arrDict.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("name")?.lowercaseString?.containsString(text.lowercaseString)) == true)
            {
                arrSearch.addObject(arrDict.objectAtIndex(i));
            }
        }

        TableViewList.reloadData();

    }
```

Edited :

```
import UIKit

class Businessdata: NSObject {

    var BusinessName: String?
    var BusinessEmail: String?
    var BusinessLatLng: NSArray?
    var Address: String?
    var ContactNumber: String?
    var WebsiteUrl: String?
    var Specialities:Array<String>?
    var StoreImages: NSArray?
    var Languages:Array<String>?
    var PaymentMethod:Array<String>?
    var OpenHours: [NSDictionary]?
    var Rating: Float?
    var Updated_date: String?
    var FeaturedBusiness: NSDictionary?

    init(json: NSDictionary)
    {
        self.BusinessName = json["business_name"] as? String
        self.BusinessEmail = json["business_email"] as? String
        self.BusinessLatLng = json["latlng"] as? NSArray
        self.Address = json["location"] as? String
        self.ContactNumber = json["phone_no"] as? String
        self.WebsiteUrl = json["website_url"] as? String
        self.Specialities = json["specialities"] as? Array<String>
        self.StoreImages = json["images"] as? NSArray
        self.Languages = json["languages"] as? Array<String>
        self.PaymentMethod = json["method_payment"] as? Array<String>
        self.OpenHours = json["opening_hours"] as? [NSDictionary]
        self.Rating = json["__v"] as? Float
        self.Updated_date = json["updated_at"] as? String

        if((json["featured_business"]) != nil)
        {
            self.FeaturedBusiness = json["featured_business"] as? NSDictionary
        }
    }

}
```

Here i have posted the Bussinessdata class code.Now how to solve for my problem
Help me out!!

Comment: You're trying to use Swift objects as if they were `NS` objects.  That is going to lead to many errors.  I suggest writing actual Swift code.

Comment: Your use of iteration is deprecated in at least Swift 2. Better go for `for i in 0 ..< arrDict.count`. Then, as penatheboss stated, there is no member `objectAtIndex` for Swift Arrays. You need to go for `arrDict[index].objectForKey.("key"?)`...

Comment: Have you just converted Obj-C to Swift using some tool?

Comment: paste code of class Businessdata

Comment: i change the correct name ,But that alo din work

Comment: WTF. It seems that you have been copying some outdated code from the internet. I wouldn't want to see any objectAtIndex in Objective-C code. I would most absolutely definitely not want to see any objectAtIndex in Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `objectAtIndex` in an array. You need to do something like this:

```
arrDict[i]
```

Instead of

```
arrDict.objectAtIndex(i)
```

**Edit**

As we discussed in the comments this is what you need

```
if((arrDict[i].name.lowercaseString?.containsString(text.lower‌​caseString)) == true)
```

Comment: now i am getting another error `` Value of type 'Businessdata' has no member 'objectForKey'`..

Comment: in this line `if((arrDict[i].objectForKey("name")?.lowercaseString?.containsString(text.lowercaseString)) == true)1

Comment: Is BuisnessData a custom class

Comment: Is name a variable in your class? If it is not, create it then say arrDict[i] .name

Comment: Now how to rewite my code with your solution with if statement

Comment: i rewite to like this `if((arrDict[i].objectForKey("name")? as! String.lowercaseString?.containsString(text.lowercaseString)) == true)` But it asking me to add more commas

Comment: `if((arrDict[i].BusinessName!.lowercaseString.containsString(text.lower‌​caseString)) == true)  ` now again error that `  Value of type 'String' has no member 'lower‌​caseString' `

Comment: Begin typing arrDict[i].BusinessName. Xcode will predict what you are typing. Click a screenshot of the auto correct and post it

Comment: Forget my earlier comment. On a different line, type print(arrDict[i].BusinessName)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
func searchMethod(notification:NSNotification)
    {

    isSearching = true;

    let text:String = notification.userInfo!["text"] as! String;

    arrSearch = [];

    for(var i=0;i<arrDict.count;i++)
    {
        if((arrDict[i].BusinessName.lowercaseString?.containsString(text.lower‌​caseString)) == true)
        {
            arrSearch.addObject(arrDict[i]);// or arrSearch.append(arrDict[i])
        }
    }

    TableViewList.reloadData();

}
```

Comment: same error `Value of type 'String' has no member 'lower‌​caseString`

Answer (score 1):

`objectAtIndex:` belongs to `NSArray` and `objectForKey:` belongs to `NSDictionary`.
Both are not available for the Swift native types.

But there are two fatal issues:

`Businessdata` is a custom class which does not respond to `objectForKey:` at all, and there is no property `name` in the class.

Assuming you are talking about the property `BusinessName` and the logic is supposed to filter all `Businessdata` instances whose lowercase string of `BusinessName` contains the search string you might write

```
arrSearch = [Businessdata]()

for item in arrDict {
  if let businessName = item.BusinessName as? String where businessName.lowercaseString.containsString(text.lowercaseString) {
    arrSearch.append(item)
  }
}
```

or *swifiter*

```
arrSearch = arrDict.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
  if let businessName = item.BusinessName as? String {
    return businessName.lowercaseString.containsString(text.lowercaseString)
  }
  return false
})
```

And please conform to the naming convention and use always variable names starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Why do you ask for use var names with lowercase letter? Naming convenction - it's up to anyone, isn't it? I consider this right in certain cases, but when developing your App, swift offers many ways do to your code as comfortable as you need